# Need to update a jsonModel using a key value

Tags: sapui5

so I have a json model that looks like this:

```js
results = [
  {
    Answer: "N",
    AnswerSelected: "Y",
    Display: "X",
    ParentOption: "",
    ParentQuestion: "",
    QuestionId: "quest1",   //<-- The key for the object
    QuestionSeq: "001",
    QuestionText: "this is question one?",
  },
  ...
]
```

So in the array I have 5 items (index 0,1,2,3 & 4). I want to be able to edit some information by providing the questionId which will be different accross all of them. So the questionId would be the key for the model but would I have loop through the model or is there a quicker way to get the result no to then modify it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop :(

Find the index of your item and use that in the binding paths: `/0/QuestionText`. Or do something like `view.bindElement("/"+index);` to use relative binding paths (without leading `/`) in your view.

Depending on your app another way might be to convert the model data to a map like so:

```js
var converted = {};
results.forEach(function(item){ converted[item.QuestionId] = item; });
myJsonModel.setData(converted);
```

You can then use bindingpaths like `/001/QuestionText`.

Beware that you have to wait for you model to be loaded in all cases before you can search for the key or convert the data. You could do that by using the [Model.requestCompleted](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Model.html#event:requestCompleted) event.